# Examples of one-to-one and onto functions $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Give examples of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ with the following properties: 
i. one-to-one but not onto

ii. onto but not one-to-one

iii. both onto and one-to-one

iv. neither one-to-one nor onto

Here's my solution:

i. $y = x^2$ from the set of non-negative real numbers to the set of all real numbers

ii. $y = x^2$ from the set of all real numbers to the set of non-negative real numbers

iii. $y = x^2$ from the set of non-negative real numbers to the set of non-negative real numbers 
iv. $y = x^2$ from the set of all real numbers to the set of all real numbers

Do you think my answers are correct?

Comment: But they must be from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$, mustn't they?

Answer (score 2):

**i.**  This is certainly injective because $(-x)^2$ will be unique for unique $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$.  However, it cannot be surjective since you aren't mapping onto any negative reals.

**ii**. That is certainly correct.  $(-x)^2$ and $x^2$ will map to the same element, so the function is not injective.  However, every element in $\mathbb{R}^+$ has a square root, so it must be a surjective mapping to the non-negative reals.

**iii**. Is also correct.  The problem with **ii** not being injective has been resolved by restricting the function's domain to the non-negative real numbers.

**iv**. Is correct.  Certainly, it cannot be surjective since you aren't mapping onto the negative reals.  It cannot be injective because $(-x)^2$ = $x^2$.

---

In short, you are partiallly correct.  The only thing is that it looks like your problem statement requires your functions be defined as $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1):

You must give functions with domain and codomain equals to $\mathbb{N}$.

One possible solution is:

i. $f(x)=2x$
$f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow 2x=2y \Rightarrow x=y$
So $f$ is one-to-one.
There is no $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2x=1$, so $f$ is not onto.

ii. $f(1)=1$ and $f(x)=x-1$ if $x>1$
$f(1)=f(2)=1$, so $f$ is not one-to-one.
$\forall x\in\mathbb{N}, f(x+1)=x$, so $f$ is onto.

iii. $f(x)=x$

iv. $f(x)=1$
$f(1)=1=f(2)$, so $f$ is not one-to-one.
There is no $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)=2$, so $f$ is not onto.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for (i) $x \rightarrow x+1$ (ii) $1 \rightarrow 1$, and for $x \neq 1, x \rightarrow x-1$, can you do (iii) and (iv) now?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\mathbb{N}$ does not include any negative numbers, so i, ii and iv are partially incorrect. $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ (or even sometimes $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, ...\}$).